# jQuery plugin unrecognized expression: [object Object]

Tags: jquery

I'm learning jQuery and trying to create a simple color changing plugin by following this [jQuery Tutorial](https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/), but can't get to work.

Here is the code:

```
(function ( $ ) {
    $.fn.changecolor = function() {
        $(this+" .green_btn").click(function() {
            $(this+" .green_text").css( "color", "green" );
        });
    };    
}( jQuery ));


jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $("#textchanger").changecolor();
});
```

Why it's not working showing error

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [object Object]
>   .green_btn

Comment: What do you expect `this+" .green_btn"` to be? `this` is most likely an object. You can’t simply concatenate an arbitrary object with a string.

Comment: If `this` is an `Element`, try `$(this).find(".green_btn")` if you intend to find all `.green_btn` elements inside `this`.

Comment: Use `$(this).find(".green_btn")` instead.

Comment: I expect `this+" .green_btn"` = `#anyID .green_btn`
so, I can use multiple time on same page with same function.
Example: `$("#textchanger").changecolor();` ,  `$("#Anothertextchanger").changecolor();` ,  `$("#AnotherThirdtextchanger").changecolor();` etc.

Comment: `this` isn’t `#anyID`. If `this` is a jQuery object, there may be a way to extract the original selector, but `.find` is the best approach here.

Comment: Great! thanks. It's working now after using `.find`.